# Making a new page in php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a website that is written in php and mysql and I want to make contact us page to be linked by another age (make a new page for contact us to be linked by the existing page)
I created a new page called contactus2.php and linked it in the following way (the same way I see how they linked in header page)

```html
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url("pages/contactus2"); ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a></li>
```

What else I should do? do I need to mention the file name in somewhere else in code?
noticing that the website also has an admin panel for user interface (in case it may help)
Sorry for my question I have no experience in making code with php and mysql and I'm experiencing with this website.

Comment: Not enough context to give a useful answer e.g. `site_url` is not a standard PHP function so we can't know what that does.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. What I'm trying to understand is that what should I do after creating a new php page to make this page working on website? how to know if the page linked with mysql ? and what I should do if the page linked with mysql?

Comment: It depends on the architecture of your application as unfortunately with PHP, there is no out-of-the-box standardised way that routing to pages can work - you should validate whether your site is built on WordPress as tagged by @JustCarty which will help a lot :-)

Comment: @Marty Yes you are absolutely right. Unfortunately I'm not the one who developed the website and the architecture of the website is not clear at all. I see that the developer of the website used only one specific page that has all the rights to create any page in the website, I really took some time to figure out this. Thank you for your reply all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just say this:

## PHP:

```
<?php $newSite = "contactus2.php"; ?>
```

## HTML:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $newSite; ?>"></a></li>
```

This is the simplest way it seems to me.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
<li><a href="pagename.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a></li>
```

this will take you to the specified page.